# Listbox not staying populated in Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox

Firefox is causing a few problems for me at the moment and I can't quite figure them out.

I have two listboxes, one is populated when the page is loaded, and the other when an item from the first is selected then click view button. The problem I am having is the 2nd listbox populates for just a split second and then everything is deleted. The function works in all other browsers I have tested.. IE, Chrome, and Safari..

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using DAL;

namespace ACESAdmin2.AcesSetup
{
public partial class storefront : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private string selectedCustomer
    {
        get { return Session["selectedCustomer"] != null ? (string)Session["selectedCustomer"] : string.Empty; }
        set { Session["selectedCustomer"] = value; }
    }
    private string selectedCatalog
    {
        get { return Session["selectedCatalog"] != null ? (string)Session["selectedCatalog"] : string.Empty; }
        set { Session["selectedCatalog"] = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadPage();
        }
    }

    private void LoadPage()
    {

        initControls();

        #region role setting
        try
        {
            //check user role to determine editing rights
            string usersRole = Roles.GetRolesForUser(Membership.GetUser().UserName)[0];
            MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
            switch (usersRole)
            {
                case "BasicUser":
                    AlignTextNoneRadio.Enabled = false;
                    AlignTextLeftRadio.Enabled = false;
                    AlignRightRadio.Enabled = false;
                    AlignCenterRadio.Enabled = false;
                    headerText.Enabled = false;
                    returnPolicy.Enabled = false;
                    welcomeMessageTextBox.Enabled = false;
                    homeText.Enabled = false;
                    homeLink.Enabled = false;
                    updateStoreButton.Enabled = false;
                    break;

                case "Customer":
                    homeLink.Enabled = false;
                    homeText.Enabled = false;
                    break;

                case "SalesRep":
                case "Admin":
                case "SuperAdmin":
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        catch (NullReferenceException error)
        {
            string message;
            message = error.ToString();
            Response.Redirect("../error.aspx");
        }
        #endregion

        #region Accordion Pane Settings

        if (ViewState["SelectedAccordionIndex"] == null)
        {
            MyAccordion.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            MyAccordion.SelectedIndex = (int)ViewState["SelectedAccordionIndex"];
        }
        #endregion
    }
    private void initControls()
    {
        //Viewable to all
        #region customer label
        if (selectedCustomer != null)
        {
            string customerName = DAL.Util.getCustomerName().ToString();
            if (customerName != null || customerName != String.Empty)
            {
                lblCustomer.Text = "Customer: <font color=maroon>" + customerName + "</font>";
                lblCustomer.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                lblCustomer.Text = "Customer: <font color=maroon>" + selectedCustomer.ToString() + "</font>";
                lblCustomer.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        //Edit Store Front
        #region Populate Fields

        #region headerAlign

        string headerAlign = DAL.Util.getHeaderAlign().ToString();
        switch (headerAlign)
        {
            case "left":
                AlignTextLeftRadio.Checked = true;
                break;
            case "center":
                AlignCenterRadio.Checked = true;
                break;
            case "right":
                AlignRightRadio.Checked = true;
                break;
            default:
                AlignTextNoneRadio.Checked = true;
                break;
        }
        #endregion

        welcomeMessageTextBox.Text = DAL.Util.getWelcome().ToString();
        headerText.Text = DAL.Util.getHeaderText().ToString();
        returnPolicy.Text = DAL.Util.getReturn().ToString();
        homeLink.Text = DAL.Util.getHomeLink().ToString();
        homeText.Text = DAL.Util.getHomeText().ToString();
        #endregion

        //BJIT Setup
        #region popultae fields
        ddlSelectVendor.DataSource = DAL.Util.getVendors();
        ddlSelectVendor.DataBind();
        listCatalogs.DataSource = DAL.Util.getCatalogs();
        listCatalogs.DataBind();
        #endregion

    }

    protected void returnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Takes user back to main admin page
        Response.Redirect("../Admin/mainAdmin.aspx");
    }

    protected void dropdownlist_SelectedInexChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewState["SelectedAccordionIndex"] = MyAccordion.SelectedIndex;
    }

    protected void updateStoreButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch(MyAccordion.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
            #region Header Value
            string selectedHeaderAlign = null;
            foreach (Control control in this.RadioPanel.Controls)
            {
                if (control is RadioButton)
                {
                    RadioButton radio = control as RadioButton;
                    if (radio.Checked)
                    {
                        selectedHeaderAlign = radio.Text.ToLower();
                    }
                }
            }
            #endregion
            //updates customer information in the table
            string sqlSf = "Update Store SET HeaderAlign = @HeaderAlign, HeaderText=@HeaderText, ReturnPolicy=@ReturnPolicy, WelcomeMessage=@WelcomeMessage, HomeTextLink=@HomeTextLink, HomeLink=@HomeLink"
                + " WHERE CustomerID='" + HttpContext.Current.Session["selectedCustomer"].ToString() + "'";
            //setting parameters
            #region Parameter Values
            AdoUtil.ACESSQLParameterCollection parameters = new AdoUtil.ACESSQLParameterCollection();
            AdoUtil.ACESSQLParameter param = new AdoUtil.ACESSQLParameter();



            param.ParamName = "@HeaderAlign";
            param.ParamValue = selectedHeaderAlign.ToString();
            param.ParamDBType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            parameters.Add(param);

            param = new AdoUtil.ACESSQLParameter();
            param.ParamName = "@HeaderText";
            param.ParamValue = headerText.Text.ToString();
            param.ParamDBType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            parameters.Add(param);

            param = new AdoUtil.ACESSQLParameter();
            param.ParamName = "@ReturnPolicy";
            param.ParamValue = returnPolicy.Text.ToString();
            param.ParamDBType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            parameters.Add(param);

            param = new AdoUtil.ACESSQLParameter();
            param.ParamName = "@WelcomeMessage";
            param.ParamValue = welcomeMessageTextBox.Text.ToString();
            param.ParamDBType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            parameters.Add(param);

            param = new AdoUtil.ACESSQLParameter();
            param.ParamName = "@HomeTextLink";
            param.ParamValue = homeText.Text.ToString();
            param.ParamDBType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            parameters.Add(param);

            param = new AdoUtil.ACESSQLParameter();
            param.ParamName = "@HomeLink";
            param.ParamValue = homeLink.Text.ToString();
            param.ParamDBType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            parameters.Add(param);
            #endregion
            AdoUtil.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlSf, parameters);
            break;
            case 1:
                //BJIT Updates
            string sqlBJIT = "Update";
            break;

            default:
            break;

        }
        MyAccordion.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    #region BJIT Control Events
    //BJIT Button
    protected void btnAddCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listItems.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            ArrayList removeArr = new ArrayList();

            listItemProfiles.SelectedIndex = -1;

            //Copy selected items to listItemProfiles
            foreach (ListItem li in listItems.Items)
            {
                if (li.Selected)
                {
                    listItemProfiles.Items.Add(li);
                    removeArr.Add(li);
                }
            }

            //Remove the selected items from listItems
            foreach (ListItem li in removeArr)
            {
                listItems.Items.Remove(li);
            }
            Util.WebFunctions.SortListBox(listItemProfiles);
        }
    }

    //BJIT Button
    protected void btnRemoveCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listItemProfiles.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            ArrayList removeArr = new ArrayList();
            listItems.SelectedIndex = -1;

            //Copy selected items to listItems
            foreach (ListItem li in listItemProfiles.Items)
            {
                if (li.Selected)
                {
                    li.Selected = false;
                    listItems.Items.Add(li);
                    removeArr.Add(li);
                }
            }

            //Remove the selected items from listItemProfiles
            foreach (ListItem li in removeArr)
            {
                listItemProfiles.Items.Remove(li);
            }
            Util.WebFunctions.SortListBox(listItems);
        }
    }

    //BJIT Button
    protected void viewBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listCatalogs.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            listItemCatalogs.DataSource = DAL.Util.getCatalogProfile(listCatalogs.SelectedValue.ToString());
            listItemCatalogs.DataBind();                
        }
    }

    //BJIT Button
    protected void editBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listCatalogs.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            #region controls visible
            lblVendor.Visible = true;
            ddlSelectVendor.Visible = true;
            lblItemProfile.Visible = true;
            lblItems.Visible = true;
            listItems.Visible = true;
            listItemProfiles.Visible = true;
            btnAddCustomer.Visible = true;
            btnRemoveCustomer.Visible = true;

            lblItemsCatalog.Visible = false;
            listItemCatalogs.Visible = false;
            //listItemCatalogs.Items.Clear();
            #endregion

            #region disable controls
            //listCatalogs.Enabled = false;
            listItemCatalogs.Enabled = false;
            editBtn.Enabled = false;
            viewBtn.Enabled = false;
            #endregion

            listItemProfiles.DataSource = DAL.Util.getCatalogProfile(listCatalogs.SelectedValue.ToString());
            listItemProfiles.DataBind();

        }
    }

    //BJIT Drop Down List
    protected void ddlSelectVendor_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listItems.DataSource = DAL.Util.getVenorItems(ddlSelectVendor.SelectedItem.ToString());
        listItems.DataBind();
    }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

With this there is a little more functionality that was not described previously and with this Firefox also does not keep the data / keep the controls visible when the editBtn_Click is initiated.

And again if there is anything i can clear up I will do my best to reword or anything.

Thank you.

Comment: If it's populated for a split-second, it's likely you have some client-side JavaScript clearing our your values

Comment: Dave makes a good comment for a first thing to check.  Further, are you using ASP.NET Ajax that might be making another call back/do you have code anywhere else in the page that clears the values (i.e. in the Page_Load event).  If you do, it would be handy to set some breakpoints or put debug lines in there to make sure those aren't getting executed afterwards.

Comment: Exactly do you have any javascript or any code in the page_load event? are you doing anything on the load if is postback? can you place your full code-behind here? thanks

Comment: I do not run any java script on this page. And I will update with full code behind. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly know what happened, but it is working now. I rebuilt the .cs page and recompiled the whole site and everything works. Also cleared the cache of all browsers..